# How to Access Oracle Table through bash when it's a new create table

Tags: bash, oracle, unix

I have a simple script in  bash that just return the count of a given table

The trow command through bash its like that

```
user>bash Bash_Script.bsh  -T MyTableTthatAlreadyExists
```

After the conections parameters it just do that:

```
    SQLSTRING="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $SYBTAB;"

    BATCH_ARGS=`sqlplus -S /nolog <<SQL | tail -1
      connect $ORCL_USR/$ORCL_PWD@$ORCL_TNS;
      alter session set nls_date_format='YYYYMMDD';
      set pagesize 0 long 4096 linesize 32767 feed off head off;
      $SQLSTRING
      quit;
SQL`

echo "$BATCH_ARGS"
```

And it works. Yest it works, it returns the nummer of rows of my table.
The problem come when I create a new table MyNewTable
 - The table exists in Oracle 
so when I do in SQL Developer

```
  select count(*) from MyNewTable;
```

return the correct nummer.

But when I throw again the unix command. It doesnt work, it doesnt return anything

```
 user>bash Bash_Script.bsh  -T MyNewTable --> return nothing
```

I wonder myself what I m missing, wat I m not taking account.
I thounk about Grant privileges but they both haven the same.

can anyone here help me ? 
Thanks in advance, Enrique

Comment: You get nothing at all - not an error? Are you sure your script is reaching that code? And are you sure you're connected to the DB as the same user through your script and SQL Developer; and indeed to the same DB? (You should see an error though if not...)

Comment: @AlexPoole no errors. just like if the Table would be empty. In the bash script i just change the name of the table , with the old table  return the count with the new return nothing. No Idea why,
- both Tables are in the same schema and DB , both of them can I access throw SQL Developer, but  i just reach the old throw unix.
- ist not a commit problem or so.

Comment: You should see zero reported for an empty table, not nothing at all.

Comment: @AlexPoole But I see nothing at all. So i suposse is noth reaching the Table i dont know why.

Comment: Take out the `| tail -1` and see what you get back - pretty sure that will show an error now. Presumably to do with privileges, as long as you have the table name right (and it isn't a quoted identifier). If you move the `alter session` - which currently seems pointless anyway - after the `set ... feed off ..` then you won't need that tail anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry to ask such easy thing.. but where should Í allocate the     | tail - 1  command

Comment: The code you posted has `BATCH_ARGS=\`sqlplus -S /nolog <<SQL | tail -1` and I'm suggesting to remove the end of that line so it becomes just `BATCH_ARGS=\`sqlplus -S /nolog <<SQL`. Then when you `echo "$BATCH_ARGS"` you'll see more useful output.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks Alex , you were right 
 ORA-01031: insufficient privileges , Thanks to put me on track of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is only getting the last line of output from SQL*Plus

```
BATCH_ARGS=`sqlplus -S /nolog <<SQL | tail -1
```

If you remove the `tail` part:

```
BATCH_ARGS=`sqlplus -S /nolog <<SQL
```

then you'll see what is actually happening. With a table that exists, with that modification I see:

```
user>bash Bash_Script.bsh  -T MyTableTthatAlreadyExists

Session altered.

      1815
```

and with a table that does not exist I see:

```
user>bash Bash_Script.bsh  -T MyNewTable

Session altered.

      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t43
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

It seems you are seeing `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`, so the user you are connecting as needs to have select privileges granted for the new table.

---

As you only want the actual count, if you swap the order of the `alter` and `set` clauses the `Session altered.` message will also be suppressed as feedback will be switched off by then:

```
    BATCH_ARGS=`sqlplus -S /nolog <<SQL
      connect $ORCL_USR/$ORCL_PWD@$ORCL_TNS;
      set pagesize 0 long 4096 linesize 32767 feed off head off;
      alter session set nls_date_format='YYYYMMDD';
      $SQLSTRING
      quit;
SQL`
```

and you'd then see, for an existing table, just:

```
user>bash Bash_Script.bsh  -T MyTableTthatAlreadyExists
      1815
```

making the `tail` unnecessary anyway.